# Reflect.Emit Dynamic Type Memory Blowup

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, reflection.emit

Using C# 3.5 I am trying to generate dynamic types at runtime using reflection emit. I used the [Dynamic Query Library](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) sample from Microsoft to create a class generator. Everything works, my problem is that 100 generated types inflate the memory usage by approximately 25MB. This is a completely unacceptable memory profile as eventually I want to support having several hundred thousand types generated in memory.

Memory profiling shows that the memory is apparently being held by various System.Reflection.Emit types and methods though I can't figure out why. I haven't found others talking about this problem so I am hoping someone in this community either knows what I am doing wrong or if this is expected behavior.

Contrived Example below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace SmallRelfectExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int typeCount = 100;
            int propCount = 100;
            Random rand = new Random();
            Type dynType = null;
            SlimClassFactory scf = new SlimClassFactory();
            for (int i = 0; i < typeCount; i++)
            {
                List<DynamicProperty> dpl = new List<DynamicProperty>(propCount);
                for (int j = 0; j < propCount; j++)
                {
                    dpl.Add(new DynamicProperty("Key" + rand.Next().ToString(), typeof(String)));
                }
                dynType = scf.CreateDynamicClass(dpl.ToArray(), i);
                //Optionally do something with the type here
            }
            Console.WriteLine("SmallRelfectExample: {0} Types generated.", typeCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class SlimClassFactory
    {
        private readonly ModuleBuilder module;
        public SlimClassFactory()
        {
            AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName("DynamicClasses");
            AssemblyBuilder assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("Module");

        }
        public Type CreateDynamicClass(DynamicProperty[] properties, int Id)
        {
            string typeName = "DynamicClass" + Id.ToString();
            TypeBuilder tb = module.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Class |
                TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(DynamicClass));
            FieldInfo[] fields = GenerateProperties(tb, properties);
            GenerateEquals(tb, fields);
            GenerateGetHashCode(tb, fields);
            Type result = tb.CreateType();
            return result;
        }
        static FieldInfo[] GenerateProperties(TypeBuilder tb, DynamicProperty[] properties)
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = new FieldBuilder[properties.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
            {
                DynamicProperty dp = properties[i];
                FieldBuilder fb = tb.DefineField("_" + dp.Name, dp.Type, FieldAttributes.Private);
                PropertyBuilder pb = tb.DefineProperty(dp.Name, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, dp.Type, null);
                MethodBuilder mbGet = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + dp.Name,
                    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                    dp.Type, Type.EmptyTypes);
                ILGenerator genGet = mbGet.GetILGenerator();
                genGet.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                genGet.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fb);
                genGet.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                MethodBuilder mbSet = tb.DefineMethod("set_" + dp.Name,
                    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                    null, new Type[] { dp.Type });
                ILGenerator genSet = mbSet.GetILGenerator();
                genSet.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                genSet.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                genSet.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fb);
                genSet.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                pb.SetGetMethod(mbGet);
                pb.SetSetMethod(mbSet);
                fields[i] = fb;
            }
            return fields;
        }
        static void GenerateEquals(TypeBuilder tb, FieldInfo[] fields)
        {
            MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod("Equals",
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot |
                MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                typeof(bool), new Type[] { typeof(object) });
            ILGenerator gen = mb.GetILGenerator();
            LocalBuilder other = gen.DeclareLocal(tb);
            Label next = gen.DefineLabel();
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Isinst, tb);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, other);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, other);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, next);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            gen.MarkLabel(next);
            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                Type ft = field.FieldType;
                Type ct = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(ft);
                next = gen.DefineLabel();
                gen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, ct.GetMethod("get_Default"), null);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, other);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                gen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, ct.GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { ft, ft }), null);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, next);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                gen.MarkLabel(next);
            }
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
        static void GenerateGetHashCode(TypeBuilder tb, FieldInfo[] fields)
        {
            MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod("GetHashCode",
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot |
                MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator gen = mb.GetILGenerator();
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                Type ft = field.FieldType;
                Type ct = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(ft);
                gen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, ct.GetMethod("get_Default"), null);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                gen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, ct.GetMethod("GetHashCode", new Type[] { ft }), null);
                gen.Emit(OpCodes.Xor);
            }
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
    }
    public abstract class DynamicClass
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            PropertyInfo[] props = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("{");
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0) sb.Append(", ");
                sb.Append(props[i].Name);
                sb.Append("=");
                sb.Append(props[i].GetValue(this, null));
            }
            sb.Append("}");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
    public class DynamicProperty
    {
        private readonly string name;
        private readonly Type type;

        public DynamicProperty(string name, Type type)
        {
            if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
            if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        }

        public Type Type
        {
            get { return type; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI this is actually a little worse in .NET 4.0.

Comment: You may have better performance using the CCI or Mono.Cecil.

Comment: @leppie thanks for the CCI suggestion. I am looking into using that instead. I am uncomfortable having to use reflection the way I am to fix the issue.

Comment: @leppie FYI CCI doesn't currently support the ability to emit into a dynamic assembly. I suppose I could persist, load, and mutate instead, but that has some negative connotations for the environment I am working in.

Comment: I think internally dynamic assemblies does the same. But it is a concern of mine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is a static field in `ModuleBuilder` holding onto the memory, and that will never get GC'd. I cant recall which field and what it contained now, but this can be seen from within SOS in WinDbg.

The good news is that .NET 4 supports GC-able dynamic assemblies  :)

Comment: @leppie It turns out that each dynamic type in the assembly keeps a reference to the ModuleBuilder and subsequent TypeBuilder which it uses for Type name conflict resolution. If you ensure that there are no name conflicts you can clear the TypeBuilder list and free all the memory without any negative side effects. (At least so far)

Comment: @leppie How I can call "Clear" on the ModuleBuilder private varible m__TypeBuilderList?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be an actual memory leak in System.Reflection.Emit. **NEW SOLUTION BELOW** I was able to get rid of most of the memory used up by using reflection and a manual dispose process. I used extension methods to add a Dispose method on some of the types. This doesn't clean up everything but the code shows how to do it. I am moving on to a different way of getting the result I need. The code is here for those interested in how to do it.

In the original sample you would call `tb.Dispose()` on your TypeBuilder instance after you have generated the type. The extension methods are below, remember **THIS DOES NOT CLEAN UP EVERYTHING** but does get most of the memory freed. This code is also not optimized for speed. There are ways to speed up the reflection used, this is just an example. **Use at your own risk.**

```
  public static void Dispose(this TypeBuilder tb)
        {
            if (tb == null)
                return;
            Type tbType = typeof(TypeBuilder);
            FieldInfo tbMbList = tbType.GetField("m_listMethods", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); //List<MethodBuilder>
            FieldInfo tbDecType = tbType.GetField("m_DeclaringType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//TypeBuilder
            FieldInfo tbGenType = tbType.GetField("m_genTypeDef", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//TypeBuilder
            FieldInfo tbDeclMeth = tbType.GetField("m_declMeth", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//MethodBuilder
            FieldInfo tbMbCurMeth = tbType.GetField("m_currentMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//MethodBuilder
            FieldInfo tbMod = tbType.GetField("m_module", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//ModuleBuilder
            FieldInfo tbGenTypeParArr = tbType.GetField("m_inst", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); //GenericTypeParameterBuilder[] 

            TypeBuilder tempDecType = tbDecType.GetValue(tb) as TypeBuilder;
            tempDecType.Dispose();
            tbDecType.SetValue(tb, null);
            tempDecType = tbGenType.GetValue(tb) as TypeBuilder;
            tempDecType.Dispose();
            tbDecType.SetValue(tb, null);

            MethodBuilder tempMeth = tbDeclMeth.GetValue(tb) as MethodBuilder;
            tempMeth.Dispose();
            tbDeclMeth.SetValue(tb,null);
            tempMeth = tbMbCurMeth.GetValue(tb) as MethodBuilder;
            tempMeth.Dispose();
            tbMbCurMeth.SetValue(tb, null);

            ArrayList mbList = tbMbList.GetValue(tb) as ArrayList;
            for (int i = 0; i < mbList.Count; i++)
            {
                tempMeth = mbList[i] as MethodBuilder;
                tempMeth.Dispose();
                mbList[i] = null;
            }
            tbMbList.SetValue(tb, null);

            ModuleBuilder tempMod = tbMod.GetValue(tb) as ModuleBuilder;
            tempMod.Dispose();
            tbMod.SetValue(tb, null);

            tbGenTypeParArr.SetValue(tb, null);
        }
        public static void Dispose(this MethodBuilder mb)
        {
            if (mb == null)
                return;
            Type mbType = typeof(MethodBuilder);
            FieldInfo mbILGen = mbType.GetField("m_ilGenerator", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            //FieldInfo mbIAttr = mbType.GetField("m_iAttributes", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            FieldInfo mbMod = mbType.GetField("m_module", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); //ModuleBuilder 
            FieldInfo mbContType = mbType.GetField("m_containingType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            FieldInfo mbLocSigHelp = mbType.GetField("m_localSignature", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//SignatureHelper
            FieldInfo mbSigHelp = mbType.GetField("m_signature", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//SignatureHelper

            ILGenerator tempIlGen = mbILGen.GetValue(mb) as ILGenerator;
            tempIlGen.Dispose();
            SignatureHelper tempmbSigHelp = mbLocSigHelp.GetValue(mb) as SignatureHelper;
            tempmbSigHelp.Dispose();
            tempmbSigHelp = mbSigHelp.GetValue(mb) as SignatureHelper;
            tempmbSigHelp.Dispose();

            ModuleBuilder tempMod = mbMod.GetValue(mb) as ModuleBuilder;
            tempMod.Dispose();
            mbMod.SetValue(mb, null);

            mbILGen.SetValue(mb, null);
            mbContType.SetValue(mb, null);
            mbLocSigHelp.SetValue(mb, null);
            mbSigHelp.SetValue(mb, null);
            mbMod.SetValue(mb, null);
        }
        public static void Dispose(this SignatureHelper sh)
        {
            if (sh == null)
                return;
            Type shType = typeof(SignatureHelper);
            FieldInfo shModule = shType.GetField("m_module", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            //FieldInfo shSig = shType.GetField("m_signature", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            shModule.SetValue(sh, null);
            //shSig.SetValue(sh, null);
        }
        public static void Dispose(this ILGenerator ilGen)
        {
            if (ilGen == null)
                return;
            Type ilGenType = typeof(ILGenerator);
            FieldInfo ilSigHelp = ilGenType.GetField("m_localSignature", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//SignatureHelper
            SignatureHelper sigTemp = ilSigHelp.GetValue(ilGen) as SignatureHelper;
            sigTemp.Dispose();
            ilSigHelp.SetValue(ilGen, null);
        }
        public static void Dispose(this ModuleBuilder modBuild)
        {
            if (modBuild == null)
                return;
            Type modBuildType = typeof(ModuleBuilder);
            FieldInfo modBuildModData = modBuildType.GetField("m__moduleData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy );
            FieldInfo modTypeBuildList = modBuildType.GetField("m__TypeBuilderList", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

            ArrayList modTypeList = modTypeBuildList.GetValue(modBuild) as ArrayList;
            if(modTypeList != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < modTypeList.Count; i++)
                {
                    TypeBuilder tb = modTypeList[i] as TypeBuilder;
                    tb.Dispose();
                    modTypeList = null;
                }
                modTypeBuildList.SetValue(modBuild, null);
            }
            modBuildModData.SetValue(modBuild, null);
        }
```

**EDIT**
Found the actual cause: It appears that each Type created in the dynamic assembly holds a reference to the `ModuleBuilder` (in `Type.Module`) which in turn keeps a list of `TypeBuilder` objects. This list is scanned each time a Type is added to check for name conflicts. If you keep a `HashSet` out of the Type generation routine to ensure you don't get any name conflicts you can call Clear on the `ModuleBuilder` private variable `m__TypeBuilderList` after the `Type` is generated without any negative side effects (So Far)

Comment: How I can call "Clear" on the ModuleBuilder private varible m__TypeBuilderList?

Comment: In .NET 4.0 this changed to a `Dictionary<string, Type>` (where `Type` actually is `TypeBuilder`) with the name `m_TypeBuilderDict`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first thing I note is that you are creating a new factory, and hence new `AssemblyBuilder`, each iteration. Can you re-use the factory (creating multiple types in the same dynamic assembly)?

Comment: Great catch, it actually makes no difference. I will update the code here in a second.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the actual issue you are seeing now, I'd strongly recommend against your current approach.  Reflection.Emit was not designed to support the creation of hundreds of thousands of types (e.g. see [this connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472622/severe-performance-decrease-when-generating-many-types-into-an-assemblybuilder), although that particular issue may only apply if you're putting them all into a single dynamic assembly).  Why would you need to create that many types?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll put this issue on connect as well as I have been unable to find a solution. The reason for that many dynamic types is that I need to support the abilities for many clients to connect to an application and create new types at runtime, I then need to be able to persist and retrieve those types from a database. Unfortunately with this memory issue I will have to look at other solutions for how to do that.

Comment: @Firestrand - I can understand the need to create some types dynamically at runtime, but a hundred thousand types is __a lot__. For example, mscorlib just has a couple thousand total.

Comment: True several hundred thousand is an upper limit, but during testing with the memory leak evident even a thousand would prohibitive.