# How create Type at Runtime and unload symbols after usage

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, reflection.emit, codedom

**The Problem**

I need create type dynamicly (*without dynamic or ExpandoObject*), I need of Type to get strong type on return of my query (making dynamicly too).

I have tried use `Reflection.Emit` and `CodeDOM`, but both keep the symbols created on memory.

**My attemps**

Using `Reflection.Emit`, I've tried `AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect`, and this work, but just if I don't use the type on my Query (Dapper) and call `GC.Collect()`.

I've tried Dispose the objects of `Reflection.Emit`, but without success (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503645/reflect-emit-dynamic-type-memory-blowup?answertab=active#tab-top);

I have tried use `GC.Collect()`, `GC.SuppressFinalize()`, to release the variables, but does not work.

I have tried create the type on another AppDomain, to Unload the domain after usage, but I did can't, by two reasons: 
1. Should be use on DoCallBack, if I to do that, I can't pass the type for another methods;
2. Trying use outside DoCallBack I get the error: `"Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable."`

Anybody know how solve that?

Comment: Using a second `AppDomain` is the only way to unload a assembly from memory. Working with AppDomains can be tricky, you have to ensure that you do no pass objects across the AppDomain boundary.